# No acknowledgement from the employer

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, internship, technology, follow-up

I applied to a company for an Internship, next day I received a mail from the company  saying that my resume is shortlisted and I need to complete a programming challenge and submit it before the deadline which I did.

I sent all my files and related instructions, everything in reply to the mail 3 days ago but no acknowledgment received till now.

Should I ask him for a follow-up?

Comment: Just a suggestion - if you search for phrases like "follow up" you will see many very similar questions with lots of answers giving advice about how and when to follow up. When in doubt, pick up the phone and call the recruiter!

Comment: I wonder if companies are starting to "advertise positions" for posts that don't exist just to get specific programming solutions for free? Compare the cost of hiring 1 programmer to the cost of an advert and having 10 or 15 programmers come up with possibly different solutions...

Comment: @SolarMike, I've heard about that but it seems like an urban legend. That would be such an impractical way to get projects done. Has anyone ever given a true account of such shenanigans? Mere suspicion isn't enough!

Comment: @teego1967 I asked the question because there seem to be so many complaints about the practice on here.. - asking the question back at me seems to serve little purpose.

Comment: @SolarMike, yeah, there are complaints about this in many places, but I have yet to see a believable, non-hearsay account of this actually ever happening. What I am trying to say is perhaps it's better to not suggest this as a possibility until there's actual proof it happens?

Comment: @teego1967 so "don't ask, don't find out" - without asking, how will anyone come forward with more substantial evidence?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have done your part of submitting the assignment, now check with them for the next steps.

Shoot them an e-mail asking about

- The receipt for successful submission of your assignment
- Anything else needed from your side
- The next steps

If you do not get a response, and you have a number to call, feel free to try to reach them over phone also.